# PSQLException: This connection has been closed using HashMap passed from DAO layer

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a bad feeling I need to refactor some stuff. Essentially, I need to take an array from PostgreSQL in the DAO layer and then convert that JDBC array to either a String[] or Integer[] array.

My confusion here is that I don't think I am referencing the database connection or ResultSet, so I have no idea why I am getting this exception?:

**Exception**

This exception is thrown below when I try to convert the jdbc Array to the Object[].

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
```

**DAOImpl**

```
public HashMap<String, Object> getUser(Integer id) {
    try {
        conn = DBConnectionFactory.getDatabaseConnection("postgresql");
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        map = generateMapFromResultSet(rs);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if(conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
            if(ps != null) {
                ps.close();
            }
            if(rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
...
}

private HashMap<String, Object> generateMapFromResultSet(ResultSet rs) {

    HashMap<String, Object> returnMap = null;
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = null; 
    Integer columns = null;

    try {
        rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        columns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        while(rs.next()) {
            returnMap = new HashMap<String,Object>(columns);

            for(int index = 1; index <= columns; index++) {
                returnMap.put(rsmd.getColumnName(index), rs.getObject(index));
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return returnMap;               
}
```

**ServiceLayer**

This is the layer that takes the HashMap, iterates over the HashMap, performs a little more logic than I want in my DAO and generates a User object.

```
private User convertMapToUser(HashMap<String,Object> userMap) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    ...

    Iterator iterator = userMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();

        String columnName = (String)pair.getKey();

        switch(columnName) {
            case COLUMN1:
                try {
                    Array col1_array = (Array)pair.getValue();
                    new_col1_array = (Integer[])col1_array.getArray(); //ERROR HERE!
                }
                catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                break;
            case COLUMN2:
                try {
                    Array col2_array = (Array)pair.getValue();
                    new_col2_array = (Integer[])col2_array.getArray(); //ERROR HERE!
                }
                catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                break;
            default:
                ...
        }

        // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
        iterator.remove();
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the getArray method in the DAO layer.

```
Object obj = rs.getObject(index);
if (obj instanceof Array)
{
   obj = ((Array) obj).getArray();
}
returnMap.put(rsmd.getColumnName(index), obj);
```